# Using GitLab CI with the Python 'onbuild' image, the packages in requirements.txt don't seem to get installed

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the [Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/) environment with a test project, https://gitlab.com/khpeek/CI-test. The project has the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: python:2.7-onbuild
services:
  - rethinkdb:latest
test_job:
  script:
    - pytest
```

The problem is that the `test_job` job in the CI pipeline fails with the following error message:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.0.1 (a3da309)
  on docker-auto-scale (e11ae361)
Using Docker executor with image python:2.7-onbuild ...
Starting service rethinkdb:latest ...
Pulling docker image rethinkdb:latest ...
Using docker image rethinkdb:latest ID=sha256:23ecfb08823bc5483c6a955b077a9bc82899a0df2f33899b64992345256f22dd for service rethinkdb...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Using docker image sha256:aaecf574604a31dd49a9d4151b11739837e4469df1cf7b558787048ce4ba81aa ID=sha256:aaecf574604a31dd49a9d4151b11739837e4469df1cf7b558787048ce4ba81aa for predefined container...
Pulling docker image python:2.7-onbuild ...
Using docker image python:2.7-onbuild ID=sha256:5754a7fac135b9cae7e02e34cc7ba941f03a33fb00cf31f12fbb71b8d389ece2 for build container...
Running on runner-e11ae361-project-3083420-concurrent-0 via runner-e11ae361-machine-1491819341-82630004-digital-ocean-2gb...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/khpeek/CI-test'...
Checking out d0937f33 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ pytest
/bin/bash: line 56: pytest: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

However, there is a `requirements.txt` in the repository with the single line `pytest==3.0.7` in it. It seems to me from the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/7663560df7547e69d13b1b548675502f4e0917d1/2.7/onbuild/Dockerfile) of the `python:2.7-onbuild` image, however, that `pip install -r requirements.txt` should get run on build. So why is `pytest` not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/7663560df7547e69d13b1b548675502f4e0917d1/2.7/onbuild/Dockerfile) you linked to, you'll see `pip install -r requirements.txt` is part of an [onbuild](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild) command. This is useful if you want to create a new container from that first one and install a bunch of requirements. The `pip install -r requirements.txt` command is therefore not executed within the container in your CI pipeline and if it were, it would be executed at the very beginning, even before your gitlab repository was cloned.

I would suggest you modify your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file this way

```
image: python:2.7-onbuild
services:
  - rethinkdb:latest
test_job:
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - pytest
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be intermittent: although the first time it took 61 minutes to run the tests (which initially failed), now it takes about a minute (see screen grab below).

For reference, the testing repository is at https://gitlab.com/khpeek/CI-test. (I had to add a `before_script` with some `pip install`s to make the job succeed).

[image]